# Sails app with multiple instances on AWS - Redis/Elasticache/ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, sails.js, amazon-elb, amazon-elasticache

I'm building a Sails app that is using socket.io and see that Sails offers a method for using multiple servers via redis:

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/realtime/multi-server-environments

Since I will be placing the app on AWS, preferably with ELB (elastic load balancer) and autoscale group with multiple EC2 instances was wondering how I can handle so it doesn't need a separate redis instance?

Maybe we can use AWS Elasticache? If so - how would this be done?

Now that AWS has released the new ALB application load balancer which has websockets, could this be used to help simplify things?

Thanks in advance

**Updates for use-cases in application**

1. Allow end-user to update data dynamically from their own dashboard
   and display analytics/stats in real-time to an administrator
2. Application status' to change based on specific timings eg. at a
   given start date/time the app allows users to update data.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, you don't want to run Redis on the same servers that Sails is running on, especially if you are using AutoScaling. The Redis server needs to be a separate server that won't disappear if your environment experiences a "scale-in" event. So Redis is going to have to be on a separate "server" somewhere.

ElastiCache is just separate EC2 instances, running Redis, where AWS handles most of the management for you to the point that you can't even SSH into the instance. It's similar to how RDS works. ElastiCache will certainly work for your scenario. You might also want to look at the third-party service RedisLabs which also manages Redis instances on AWS for you.

Regarding your second question, an Application Load Balancer will have no bearing on your Redis usage. It will however bring actual support for WebSockets which it sounds like you are using. So yes, you should be using an ALB instead of an ELB.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the reply, it sounds like ElastiCache might be helpful here. While I know ElastiCache or Redis can help significantly with performance I'm a bit worried about data loss since in the end we're still just talking in-memory data. I understand the Sails team decided to use socket.io-redis but is this alone enough or must we have some backup solution as well? Reason I ask is since have considered other solutions like AWS Kinesis and SQS. Obviously using built-in Sails functionality would be easier but don't want to make any sacrifices...

Comment: You should be using Redis to cache data for quick access, and a database like MySQL to store the data long-term. That way you get the blazing fast access of Redis without losing data. I'm not sure why you are also considering Kinesis and SQS for the same role, since those are completely different types of services. Perhaps you need to add more details to your question regarding your exact use case.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Mark. I've added 2 main use cases above. For #1 redis or elasticache might work? I thought about using Kinesis solely due to the realtime element and streaming large data. However it seems this would be overkill at this time so I'd rather leave that off the table :) What about AWS SNS? Might be better to do a pubsub implementation to handle this?  This also prevents having to manage separate redis instance... However Sailsjs already easily supports socketIO.redis so it might be easier to implement... Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again!